# Creating multiple Kivy Canvas images and exporting to png: How do I do this while managing the unpredictability of kivy.clock?

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy

I have created a simplified example of my Python code below. Basically, the program generates crosses on an image with positions dictated by some data file. It then saves the image and canvas to a png file. It does this several times iteratively for different rows in the data file (below I've just used a single "pos_list" for demonstration purposes).

My problem is that in order to use export_to_png, one has to allow the screen to update and display the changes in canvas instructions. This means I need to use the Kivy Clock. HOWEVER. When I schedule multiple clock events I cannot guarantee that they will occur in the right order for some reason (even with carefully chosen timings). This is a problem because if the pngs are created before the canvas instructions take effect, they will be incomplete. Likewise, the ultimate point of my code is to create a PDF containing all of these images (the do_something_with_pages function is a placeholder for this) and if this function calls before the images are created, it will fail.

I appreciate this is a complex problem, but any insight into how to make the Clock events behave or even how to do this without using the Clock, would be much appreciated.

```
from functools import partial
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.graphics import *
from kivy.uix.label import Label

Builder.load_string('''
<NumberLabel>:
    size: 10, 15
    text_size: self.size
    color: 0, 0, 0, 1
    outline_color: 1, 1, 1
    outline_width: 1
    
<AScreen>:
    Button:
        size_hint: 0.2, 0.1
        pos_hint: {"x": 0.4, "y": 0.85}
        on_release:
            root.parent_function(8, '/some/image/file/path.png')
    Image:
        id: an_image
        size_hint: 0.8, 0.8
        pos_hint: {"x": 0.1, "y": 0}
''')

dir_path = '/some/directory'

class NumberLabel(Label):
    pass

Class AScreen(Screen):

    def parent_function(self, pages, path):

        t_interval = 0.7

        for i in range(pages):
            pos_list = [(0.2, 0.3), (0.15, 0.74)] # This is usually a list of 
                                                  # (x, y) relative 
                                                  # coordinates that is read 
                                                  # from a csv file and 
                                                  # varies per page, but here
                                                  # I have set it to 
                                                  # something fixed
            Clock.schedule_once(partial(self.draw_on_image, i, path, pos_list), t_interval * i)
            
        Clock.schedule_once(self.do_something_with_pages, (t_interval + 0.18) * pages)
        
        

    def draw_on_image(self, page, path, pos_list, *args):
        # This function draws a number of canvas objects on the image and 
        # adds a label with a number for each object drawn.
        # It is scheduled with Clock so that the canvas may later be exported 
        # as an image before it is changed by the next iteration of the loop
        self.ids.an_image.source = path
        self.ids.an_image.canvas.after.clear()
        self.ids.an_image.clear_widgets()
        image_pos = self.ids.an_image.pos
        image_width = self.ids.an_image.width
        image_height = self.ids.an_image.height
        obj_num = 0
        for item in pos_list:
            new_pos = (image_pos[0] + item[0] * image_width, image_pos[1] + item[1] * image_height)
            x1, y1 = new_pos[0] - 3, new_pos[1] - 3
            x2, y2 = new_pos[0] + 3, new_pos[1] + 3
            with self.ids.an_image.canvas.after:
                Color(1, 1, 1)
                Line(points=[(x1,y1), (x2,y2)], width=2)
                Line(points=[(x1,y2), (x2,y1)], width=2)
                Color(0, 0, 0)
                Line(points=[(x1,y1), (x2,y2)], width=1)
                Line(points=[(x1,y2), (x2,y1)], width=1)
            obj_num += 1
            l = NumberLabel(pos=(x1,y2), text=str(obj_num))
            self.ids.an_image.add_widget(l)

        Clock.schedule_once(partial(self.export_image, page), 0.002)
        
    def export_image(self, page, *args):
        # This MUST happen after the previous canvas changes show up on 
        # screen but before the next canvas changes are made
        png_path = '{dir}/image{num}.png'.format(dir=dir_path, num=page)
        self.ids.an_image.export_to_png(png_path)
        
    def do_something_with_pages(self, *args):
        # This function does something with all of the saved pngs so MUST 
        # only be called after all of the PNGs have been created
        pass
        
        
class Manager(ScreenManager):
    pass

class MainApp(App):
    def build(self):
        self.title = 'Example'
        self.sm = Manager()
        return self.sm

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = MainApp()
    app.run()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK inspired by John Anderson's answer, I've managed to crack it. Posting below for any who might need it.

I don't think it's possible to achieve the desired result from using a single Image and updating the source and canvas for each "page". Instead, I have created a separate image (within a modal view) for each "page" and then exported each of these images at the end.

```
from functools import partial
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.graphics import *
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.modalview import ModalView

Builder.load_string('''
<NumberLabel>:
    size: 10, 15
    text_size: self.size
    color: 0, 0, 0, 1
    outline_color: 1, 1, 1
    outline_width: 1
    
<AScreen>:
    Button:
        size_hint: 0.2, 0.1
        pos_hint: {"x": 0.4, "y": 0.85}
        on_release:
            root.parent_function(8, '/some/image/file/path.png')

<AModalView>:
    size_hint: 0.8, 0.8
    pos_hint: {"x": 0.1, "y": 0.1}
    FloatLayout:
        Image:
            id: an_image
''')

dir_path = '/some/directory'

class NumberLabel(Label):
    pass

class AModalView(ModalView):
    pass

Class AScreen(Screen):

    def parent_function(self, pages, path):

        self.popup_list = []

        for i in range(pages):
            pos_list = [(0.2, 0.3), (0.15, 0.74)] # This is usually a list of 
                                                  # (x, y) relative 
                                                  # coordinates that is read 
                                                  # from a csv file and 
                                                  # varies per page, but here
                                                  # I have set it to 
                                                  # something fixed
            self.draw_on_image(i, path, pos_list)
            
        Clock.schedule_once(partial(self.do_something_with_pages, pages), 0)
        

    def draw_on_image(self, page, path, pos_list, *args):
        # This function creates a popup with an image inside it.
        # It then draws a number of canvas objects on the image and 
        # adds a label with a number for each object drawn.
        self.popup_list.append(AModalView())
        self.popup_list[page - 1].open()
        self.popup_list[page - 1].ids.an_image.source = path
        image_pos = self.popup_list[page - 1].ids.an_image.pos
        image_width = self.popup_list[page - 1].ids.an_image.width
        image_height = self.popup_list[page - 1].ids.an_image.height
        obj_num = 0
        for item in pos_list:
            new_pos = (image_pos[0] + item[0] * image_width, image_pos[1] + item[1] * image_height)
            x1, y1 = new_pos[0] - 3, new_pos[1] - 3
            x2, y2 = new_pos[0] + 3, new_pos[1] + 3
            with self.popup_list[page - 1].ids.an_image.canvas.after:
                Color(1, 1, 1)
                Line(points=[(x1,y1), (x2,y2)], width=2)
                Line(points=[(x1,y2), (x2,y1)], width=2)
                Color(0, 0, 0)
                Line(points=[(x1,y1), (x2,y2)], width=1)
                Line(points=[(x1,y2), (x2,y1)], width=1)
            obj_num += 1
            l = NumberLabel(pos=(x1,y2), text=str(obj_num))
            self.popup_list[page - 1].ids.an_image.add_widget(l)
        
    def do_something_with_pages(self, pages, *args):
        # export to png for the image on each popup created, then dismiss all the 
        # popups
        for page in range(pages):
            png_path = '{dir}/image{num}.png'.format(dir=dir_path, num=page)
            self.popup_list[page - 1].ids.an_image.export_to_png(png_path)
            self.popup_list[page - 1].dismiss()
        # Now do something with all the pngs
        
        
class Manager(ScreenManager):
    pass

class MainApp(App):
    def build(self):
        self.title = 'Example'
        self.sm = Manager()
        return self.sm

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = MainApp()
    app.run()
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need that much use of `Clock.schedule_once()` in your code. You can make changes to the Image, then just call `Clock.schedule_once()` to allow kivy to update the image.

I have posted a modified version of `AScreen` class below. The modification just uses `Clock.schedule_once()` in one place. Then I added the `pages` variable to be passed down the stack to allow determining when all the files have been exported. See the comments in the code:

```
class AScreen(Screen):

    def parent_function(self, pages, path):

        t_interval = 0.7

        for i in range(pages):
            pos_list = [(0.2, 0.3), (0.15, 0.74)] # This is usually a list of
                                                  # (x, y) relative
                                                  # coordinates that is read
                                                  # from a csv file and
                                                  # varies per page, but here
                                                  # I have set it to
                                                  # something fixed

            # do not need Clock.schedule_once() here. We are already on main thread
            self.draw_on_image( i, pages, path, pos_list)   # pass pages, so we can track status

    def draw_on_image(self, page, pages, path, pos_list, *args):
        # This function draws a number of canvas objects on the image and
        # adds a label with a number for each object drawn.
        # It is scheduled with Clock so that the canvas may later be exported
        # as an image before it is changed by the next iteration of the loop
        self.ids.an_image.source = path
        self.ids.an_image.canvas.after.clear()
        self.ids.an_image.clear_widgets()
        image_pos = self.ids.an_image.pos
        image_width = self.ids.an_image.width
        image_height = self.ids.an_image.height
        obj_num = 0
        for item in pos_list:
            new_pos = (image_pos[0] + item[0] * image_width, image_pos[1] + item[1] * image_height)
            x1, y1 = new_pos[0] - 3, new_pos[1] - 3
            x2, y2 = new_pos[0] + 3, new_pos[1] + 3
            with self.ids.an_image.canvas.after:
                Color(1, 1, 1)
                Line(points=[(x1,y1), (x2,y2)], width=2)
                Line(points=[(x1,y2), (x2,y1)], width=2)
                Color(0, 0, 0)
                Line(points=[(x1,y1), (x2,y2)], width=1)
                Line(points=[(x1,y2), (x2,y1)], width=1)
            obj_num += 1
            l = NumberLabel(pos=(x1,y2), text=str(obj_num))
            self.ids.an_image.add_widget(l)

        # use Clock.schedule_once() to give main thread a chance to update image
        Clock.schedule_once(partial(self.export_image, page, pages), 0.002)  # pass pages again

    def export_image(self, page, pages, *args):
        # This MUST happen after the previous canvas changes show up on
        # screen but before the next canvas changes are made
        png_path = '{dir}/image{num}.png'.format(dir=dir_path, num=page)
        self.ids.an_image.export_to_png(png_path)
        print('exported', png_path)
        if page == pages - 1:   # use page and pages to determine if all files are done
            self.do_something_with_pages()

    def do_something_with_pages(self, *args):
        print('do something')
        # This function does something with all of the saved pngs so MUST
        # only be called after all of the PNGs have been created
        pass
```

Comment: Thanks very much John. Passing down the pages variable to determine when all files have been exported has definitely helped improve things!


The rest doesn't work as you would expect however. Unfortunately, the export_image function calls do not occur until after all the draw_on_image calls. This means that the canvas changes a bunch of times as it cycles through the pages and then the images are all exported as exactly the same image (the final one).


This is why I felt I had to put the draw_on_image function in a scheduled task as well, which is admittedly rather clumsy.